# one click execution of several nuget package manager console commands

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, nuget

I have several `Update-Database` commands in a PowerShell script file. This file is run using the NuGet Package Manager Console by entering the name of the script file.

Is it possible to run the very same script, but *without* manually opening the Package Manager Console? An extra item in the script's drop-down menu containing a "Run with NuGet PM" maybe?